# Putting switch case inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to put a switch conditional inside this map function?
I want that
if row.role = 1, then put "Student" inside RoleIndex
if row.role = 2, then put "Teacher" inside RoleIndex and so on ....
But this code below give me syntax error

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    API.GetUser().then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      setListUser(
        result.map((row) => ({
          IdIndex: row.id, // Ex: Receive 1
          NameIndex: row.name, // Ex: Receive Parker
          switch (row.role) {
            case 1:
            RoleIndex: "Student"
            break;
            case 2:
            RoleIndex: "Teacher"
            break;
            case 3:
            // do something
            break;
        }
        }))
      );

      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [props]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `put "Student" inside RoleIndex`?

Comment: Sorry, I just edit it

Comment: Instead of switch case assign your roles in an array and assign the array index as your Role Index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You would use `switch-case` before return the actual object:**

Also, don't forget to put a `default` case:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  API.GetUser().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    setListUser(
      result.map((row) => {
        let RoleIndex;
        switch (row.role) {
          case '1':
            RoleIndex = 'Student';
            break;
          case '2':
            RoleIndex = 'Teacher';
            break;
          case '3':
            // do something
            break;
          default:
            RoleIndex = '';
        }
        return {
          Id: row.id, // Ex: Receive 1
          Name: row.name, // Ex: Receive Parker
          RoleIndex,
        };
      }),
    );

    setLoading(false);
  });
}, [props]);
```

Comment: I need it actualy, coz the case is 5 or more,

Comment: @phaphapha _"I need it actualy, coz the case is 5 or more,"_ - Then might I suggest using an object/dictionary to map the number to the label, rather than a switch statement?  Should read more easily and I _think_ be more performant as well...

Comment: Does it help? @phaphapha

Comment: @RyanLe somehow this doesnt work, the data doent show on Table,

Comment: Could you provide the code where you use it? It supposes to make an array to `setListUser`

Comment: Since I use it on UseEffect, I use it before rendering page, get data from the API, the store the result on setListUser before display it on Table

Comment: Please verify if you are properly render the ` ListUser`?

Comment: Mmmm, the data is show up now on Table, I mixed up the GetUser with GetTask but I fix it,
And after I console.log the ListUser, only RoleIndex has value =""

Comment: What is in your `row.role`? Is it a string `"1"` or a number `1`?

Comment: There you go, the string "1", haha, that solve it